# Query takes 10+ minutes to execute

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm supposed to find out why this query takes more than 10 minutes to execute. Things is SQL is not my strong suit. I know it has to do with all the group by in part... But what approach am I supposed to take to optimize this.
Also I understand it would be pretty difficult for anyone to give an answer without context or knowing our database. This query should return data on warehouse employees assignation. And display the work they have done. So in other words.. Their Name, the date, the Shipping/Receiving orders they worked on, the quantity they picked/received, the time it took and what activity is linked to it

```
    SELECT  SystemeUser.SyU_NRI,
         Usager = CASE WHEN SyU_Nom IS NULL THEN '' ELSE SyU_Nom END
                  + CASE WHEN SyU_Prenom IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ', ' + SyU_Prenom END
                  + ' (' + SyU_Code + ')',
         Jour,
         JourDisplay ,
         Rec_NRI = CASE WHEN Act_NRI = 9 THEN Rec_NRI ELSE NULL END,
         QtePalRec = SUM(CASE WHEN TInv.Act_NRI = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
         SDe_NRI = CASE WHEN Act_NRI = 11 THEN SDe_NRI ELSE NULL END,
         QteUnitePick =  SUM(CASE WHEN TInv.Act_NRI = 11 THEN TInv.Inv_QteUniteOri ELSE 0 END),
         Sor_NRI =  CASE WHEN Act_NRI = 5 THEN Sor_NRI ELSE NULL END,
         QtePalShip =  SUM(CASE WHEN TInv.Act_NRI = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
         Act_NRI,
         Type_Op = CASE  WHEN Act_NRI = 9 THEN 1 
                         WHEN Act_NRI = 11 THEN 2
                         WHEN Act_NRI = 5 THEN 3
                         ELSE
                             4
                   END,
         Debut = Min(Inv_DtHr),
         Fin = Max(Inv_DtHr),
         Duree_Minute = DateDiff(minute,Min(Inv_DtHr),Max(Inv_DtHr))
     FROM SystemeUser
         INNER JOIN
                 (SELECT SyU_NRI,
                         Inventaire.Act_NRI,
                         Inv_DtHr = dbo.fct_GetDateTimeZone(Inventaire.Inv_DtHr, Lot.Ent_NRI),
                         Inv_QteUniteOri,
                         Jour = CONVERT(VARCHAR, dbo.fct_GetDateTimeZone(Inventaire.Inv_DtHr, Lot.Ent_NRI), 112),
                         JourDisplay = CONVERT(VARCHAR, dbo.fct_GetDateTimeZone(Inventaire.Inv_DtHr, Lot.Ent_NRI), 111),
                         Rec_NRI = CASE WHEN Inventaire.Act_NRI = 9 THEN Lot.Rec_NRI ELSE NULL END,
                         SDe_NRI = NULL,
                         Sor_NRI = CASE WHEN Inventaire.Act_NRI = 5 THEN Inventaire.Sor_NRI ELSE NULL END
                 FROM Inventaire  
                     INNER JOIN Lot ON Inventaire.Lot_NRI= Lot.Lot_NRI
                     INNER JOIN Actsequence
                         LEFT JOIN Wave ON Actsequence.AcS_NRi = Wave.AcS_NRI
                     ON Inventaire.AcS_NRI= Actsequence.AcS_NRI
                 WHERE Inventaire.Act_NRI IN (9,5)
                 UNION
                 SELECT waveline.SyU_NRI,
                         Inventaire.Act_NRI,
                         Inv_DtHr = dbo.fct_GetDateTimeZone(Inventaire.Inv_DtHr, Lot.Ent_NRI),
                         Inv_QteUniteOri,
                         Jour = CONVERT(VARCHAR, dbo.fct_GetDateTimeZone(Inventaire.Inv_DtHr, Lot.Ent_NRI), 112),
                         JourDisplay = CONVERT(VARCHAR, dbo.fct_GetDateTimeZone(Inventaire.Inv_DtHr, Lot.Ent_NRI), 111),
                         Rec_NRI = NULL,
                         SDe_NRI = CASE WHEN Inventaire.Act_NRI = 11 THEN  Wave.SDe_NRI ELSE NULL END,
                         Sor_NRI = NULL
                 FROM Wave 
                     INNER JOIN Lot ON Wave.Lot_NRI= Lot.Lot_NRI
                     LEFT JOIN Actsequence ON Wave.AcS_NRI= Actsequence.AcS_NRI
                     INNER JOIN WaveLine
                         INNER JOIN Inventaire ON WaveLine.Inv_NRI = Inventaire.Inv_NRI
                     ON Wave.Wav_NRI = WaveLine.Wav_NRI AND WLi_Confirm = 1
                 WHERE Inventaire.Act_NRI = 11
                 ) as TInv
          ON SystemeUser.SyU_NRI = TInv.SyU_NRI
    WHERE
         SystemeUser.SyU_NRI IN (107, 121, 85, 1, 229, 120, 177, 158, 161, 100, 88, 232, 70, 145, 75, 84, 214, 63, 192, 144, 57,    136,    113, 58, 20, 205, 176, 127, 115, 199, 142, 92, 30, 80, 163, 10, 143, 55, 18, 98, 3, 56, 155, 81, 154, 64, 156,  162, 223,  191, 183, 188, 225, 77, 5, 35, 157, 109, 152, 187, 129, 60, 190, 46, 221, 230, 218, 150, 195, 141, 106, 72,   226, 23, 15, 79,  2, 95, 175, 235, 134, 24, 114, 148, 215, 174, 140, 209, 202, 39, 94, 234, 227, 110, 228, 34, 200, 197,  133, 198, 171, 47,    11, 32, 102, 146, 194, 185, 17, 111, 169, 93, 117, 22, 151, 186, 87, 164, 137, 123, 62, 67, 103,   131, 193, 181, 49, 54, 6,     178, 160, 40, 27, 50, 130, 149, 71, 76, 8, 201, 203, 7, 53, 41, 9, 73, 48, 118, 74, 179,  101, 25, 38, 28, 33, 4, 61, 99,   128, 65, 44, 233, 36, 236, 96, 189, 112, 42, 196, 108, 37, 219, 222, 170, 16, 45,  237,105, 167, 116, 139, 182, 206, 204,  172, 173, 97, 14, 29, 211, 68, 21, 90, 69, 231, 208, 91, 19, 126, 138, 78, 207,     13, 210, 166, 52, 153, 82, 124, 184, 213,   217, 216, 51, 180, 135, 89, 125, 168, 59, 83, 132, 165, 66, 159, 220, 43,  104, 12, 119, 147, 26, 212, 122)
         AND Inv_DtHr BETWEEN  '20190304 00:00:00'  AND  '20190304 23:59:59' 
    GROUP BY     SystemeUser.SyU_NRI,
                 SyU_Code,
                 SyU_Nom,
                 SyU_Prenom,
                 Jour,
                 JourDisplay, 
                 Act_NRI, 
                 Rec_NRI,
                 Sor_NRI,
                 SDe_NRI
    ORDER BY Type_Op, Usager, Jour, Debut, Fin, Rec_NRI, SDe_NRI, Sor_NRI, 
    SyU_Nom
```

Comment: [Getting Help With A Slow Query](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/03/getting-help-with-a-slow-query/).

Comment: If you just remove order by and functions in the where clause, your query will perform much better. Possibly order by can be handled at presentation layer. And try to use direct date in where clause instead of cast.

Comment: It is still not much optimize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Disclaimer: this is a total shot in the dark.  As [Erik](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/32281/erik-darling) mentioned in the comments, you should review [Getting Help With A Slow Query](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/03/getting-help-with-a-slow-query/) and provide execution plan, index / table definitions, etc.

### The function

Your inner subquery calls this function a few times:

```
dbo.fct_GetDateTimeZone
```

Take the code from that and copy it into the query directly, rather than calling it through the function.  Functions in SQL Server can be performance killers, and scalar functions particularly so (which it looks like that one would be).

### Breaking Up

One common way of improving performance with large complex queries is to break them up into chunks.  This makes the query optimizer's job a little easier, because it has less options to consider per-query.

For your query, you could take the subquery being used in the inner join, and dump that into a temp table:

```
CREATE TABLE #TInv
(
    SyU_NRI INT NOT NULL,
    Act_NRI INT NOT NULL,
    /* all the columns you need */
);

 INSERT INTO #TInv
 SELECT SyU_NRI,
         Inventaire.Act_NRI,
         Inv_DtHr = dbo.fct_GetDateTimeZone(Inventaire.Inv_DtHr, Lot.Ent_NRI),
         Inv_QteUniteOri,
         Jour = CONVERT(VARCHAR, dbo.fct_GetDateTimeZone(Inventaire.Inv_DtHr, Lot.Ent_NRI), 112),
         JourDisplay = CONVERT(VARCHAR, dbo.fct_GetDateTimeZone(Inventaire.Inv_DtHr, Lot.Ent_NRI), 111),
         Rec_NRI = CASE WHEN Inventaire.Act_NRI = 9 THEN Lot.Rec_NRI ELSE NULL END,
         SDe_NRI = NULL,
         Sor_NRI = CASE WHEN Inventaire.Act_NRI = 5 THEN Inventaire.Sor_NRI ELSE NULL END
 FROM Inventaire  
     INNER JOIN Lot ON Inventaire.Lot_NRI= Lot.Lot_NRI
     INNER JOIN Actsequence
         LEFT JOIN Wave ON Actsequence.AcS_NRi = Wave.AcS_NRI
     ON Inventaire.AcS_NRI= Actsequence.AcS_NRI
 WHERE Inventaire.Act_NRI IN (9,5)
 UNION
 SELECT waveline.SyU_NRI,
         Inventaire.Act_NRI,
         Inv_DtHr = dbo.fct_GetDateTimeZone(Inventaire.Inv_DtHr, Lot.Ent_NRI),
         Inv_QteUniteOri,
         Jour = CONVERT(VARCHAR, dbo.fct_GetDateTimeZone(Inventaire.Inv_DtHr, Lot.Ent_NRI), 112),
         JourDisplay = CONVERT(VARCHAR, dbo.fct_GetDateTimeZone(Inventaire.Inv_DtHr, Lot.Ent_NRI), 111),
         Rec_NRI = NULL,
         SDe_NRI = CASE WHEN Inventaire.Act_NRI = 11 THEN  Wave.SDe_NRI ELSE NULL END,
         Sor_NRI = NULL
 FROM Wave 
     INNER JOIN Lot ON Wave.Lot_NRI= Lot.Lot_NRI
     LEFT JOIN Actsequence ON Wave.AcS_NRI= Actsequence.AcS_NRI
     INNER JOIN WaveLine
         INNER JOIN Inventaire ON WaveLine.Inv_NRI = Inventaire.Inv_NRI
     ON Wave.Wav_NRI = WaveLine.Wav_NRI AND WLi_Confirm = 1
 WHERE Inventaire.Act_NRI = 11;
```

Then use the temp table in the join:

```
SELECT  SystemeUser.SyU_NRI,
     Usager = CASE WHEN SyU_Nom IS NULL THEN '' ELSE SyU_Nom END
              + CASE WHEN SyU_Prenom IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ', ' + SyU_Prenom END
              + ' (' + SyU_Code + ')',
     Jour,
     JourDisplay ,
     Rec_NRI = CASE WHEN Act_NRI = 9 THEN Rec_NRI ELSE NULL END,
     QtePalRec = SUM(CASE WHEN TInv.Act_NRI = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
     SDe_NRI = CASE WHEN Act_NRI = 11 THEN SDe_NRI ELSE NULL END,
     QteUnitePick =  SUM(CASE WHEN TInv.Act_NRI = 11 THEN TInv.Inv_QteUniteOri ELSE 0 END),
     Sor_NRI =  CASE WHEN Act_NRI = 5 THEN Sor_NRI ELSE NULL END,
     QtePalShip =  SUM(CASE WHEN TInv.Act_NRI = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
     Act_NRI,
     Type_Op = CASE  WHEN Act_NRI = 9 THEN 1 
                     WHEN Act_NRI = 11 THEN 2
                     WHEN Act_NRI = 5 THEN 3
                     ELSE
                         4
               END,
     Debut = Min(Inv_DtHr),
     Fin = Max(Inv_DtHr),
     Duree_Minute = DateDiff(minute,Min(Inv_DtHr),Max(Inv_DtHr))
 FROM SystemeUser
     INNER JOIN #TInv as TInv
      ON SystemeUser.SyU_NRI = TInv.SyU_NRI
WHERE
     SystemeUser.SyU_NRI IN (107, 121, 85, 1, 229, 120, 177, 158, 161, 100, 88, 232, 70, 145, 75, 84, 214, 63, 192, 144, 57,    136,    113, 58, 20, 205, 176, 127, 115, 199, 142, 92, 30, 80, 163, 10, 143, 55, 18, 98, 3, 56, 155, 81, 154, 64, 156,  162, 223,  191, 183, 188, 225, 77, 5, 35, 157, 109, 152, 187, 129, 60, 190, 46, 221, 230, 218, 150, 195, 141, 106, 72,   226, 23, 15, 79,  2, 95, 175, 235, 134, 24, 114, 148, 215, 174, 140, 209, 202, 39, 94, 234, 227, 110, 228, 34, 200, 197,  133, 198, 171, 47,    11, 32, 102, 146, 194, 185, 17, 111, 169, 93, 117, 22, 151, 186, 87, 164, 137, 123, 62, 67, 103,   131, 193, 181, 49, 54, 6,     178, 160, 40, 27, 50, 130, 149, 71, 76, 8, 201, 203, 7, 53, 41, 9, 73, 48, 118, 74, 179,  101, 25, 38, 28, 33, 4, 61, 99,   128, 65, 44, 233, 36, 236, 96, 189, 112, 42, 196, 108, 37, 219, 222, 170, 16, 45,  237,105, 167, 116, 139, 182, 206, 204,  172, 173, 97, 14, 29, 211, 68, 21, 90, 69, 231, 208, 91, 19, 126, 138, 78, 207,     13, 210, 166, 52, 153, 82, 124, 184, 213,   217, 216, 51, 180, 135, 89, 125, 168, 59, 83, 132, 165, 66, 159, 220, 43,  104, 12, 119, 147, 26, 212, 122)
     AND Inv_DtHr BETWEEN  '20190304 00:00:00'  AND  '20190304 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY     SystemeUser.SyU_NRI,
             SyU_Code,
             SyU_Nom,
             SyU_Prenom,
             Jour,
             JourDisplay, 
             Act_NRI, 
             Rec_NRI,
             Sor_NRI,
             SDe_NRI
ORDER BY Type_Op, Usager, Jour, Debut, Fin, Rec_NRI, SDe_NRI, Sor_NRI, 
SyU_Nom
```

That allows both queries to be optimized separately, hopefully resulting in a better plan.

Answer (score 2):

Optimizing queries is not generally something random people on the internet can help with. To really help we would need to see a lot more info on how the database is built and the hardware and load levels its running on. The best we can do is to give recommendations on query writing that would hopefully help the optimizer choose a better plan and even then it may not actually make the query run faster. Take a look at the below items and try testing them out on your system to see if it helps.

1) Try removing the custom date function. Use something like "dateadd(hour,datediff(hour,,),))" instead of the function. Functions can (for reasons outside the scope of this question) cause the query to be processed row by row rather than as a set.

2) There is some weird inner join syntax in there and I am unsure how it optimizes. I recommend rewriting these inner joins to a more common syntax (unless you know its optimizing fine.)

These are the joins I'm referring to:
     INNER JOIN Actsequence
         LEFT JOIN Wave ON Actsequence.AcS_NRi = Wave.AcS_NRI
         ON Inventaire.AcS_NRI= Actsequence.AcS_NRI

Comment: Thanks I didnt notice that Ill try tempering with this.